# Rest API that needs a connection

Tags: web-services, api, rest

I have a system where the user needs to connect to first and then based on the connection fetch some data. For e.g. you connect to a database and then fetch say metadata about a table say.

I was planning to expose this via REST API. So in this case, you need to first connect and then use that connection to fetch the metadata.

Two options come to my mind:
a. Have a url say /connect where you post the connection parameters to and it returns a conneciton id. This id is then encoded in subsequent URL to identify the connection.
b. Second option is to post the connection parameters everytime.

What are the pros/cons of these approaches? Are there any other alternatives?
One constraint is that the authentication mechanism to connect to the system is not in my control, I am just exposing some data from the systems via webservices and I am exploring using REST.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to expose the connection?

I think it may just be semantic prejudice - but usually connection details are hidden by the service.

Does the connection have business value?!

If the connection does have business value, then treat it like a resource:
i.e.
do a post on /connections to return a new connection
then do a get on /connection//metadata to get the metadata about that connection.

Comment: So will the url to fetch metadata identify the connection via some id retruned in the previous connection call?